# Put an Icon in a eVB Application

Tags: icons, windows-ce, evb

Someone knows how to put an icon in a eVB 3 application, because i hate that default icon for *.vb files, something like using the registry editor or using resource files. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How To Associate an Icon with an eVB Application
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268309

It says:

> eVB applications are not compiled to
>   executable files but to binary files
>   that the Pvbload.exe executable
>   interprets. Thus, eVB applications use
>   the icon from Pvbload.exe in the same
>   way that Microsoft Excel worksheets
>   use the icon from Excel.exe. To allow
>   for a customized application icon, you
>   must create an eMbedded Visual C++
>   (eVC) application that only shells out
>   to the operating system to run the
>   application. The operating system
>   recognizes that there is a file
>   association with Pvbload.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to convert to [NS Basic/CE](http://www.nsbasic.com/ce/). It allows you to specify icons - even to meet the requirements of Windows Mobule 6.5.